# What is the best approach to import multiple react component in a file without creating performance issues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here is the thing:

I've gone to several components in my React application, but every time I import them in other files, I've got too many imports like the following:

```
components
|+comp1
|     - comp1.component.tsx
|     - comp1.styles.tsx
|+comp2
|     - comp2.component.tsx
|     - comp2.styles.tsx
|...
|
```

```
import Comp1 from "../components/comp1/comp1.component"
import Comp2 from "../components/comp2/comp2.component"
import Comp3 from "../components/comp3/comp3.component"
import Comp4 from "../components/comp4/comp4.component"
```

I haven't mentionned the in each of these folders I've the associated style file using `styled-components` that are named as following: `comp1.styles.tsx` too much my naming conventions styles.

Here are some approaches that I've used to solve this problem:

**1st Approach**

Inside every component directory i've renamed my component files into `index.tsx` and my `styled component` styles as `styles.tsx`.

Here is the result for this approach:

```
components
|+comp1
|     - index.tsx
|     - styles.tsx
|+comp2
|     - index.tsx
|     - styles.tsx
|...
|
```

```
import Comp1 from "../components/comp1/"
import Comp2 from "../components/comp2/"
import Comp3 from "../components/comp3/"
import Comp4 from "../components/comp4/"
```

**2nd Approach**

Instead of renaming components files into `index.tsx` in each folder i kept them as they were first :`comp1.component.tsx` and the style `comp1.styles.tsx`.But inside each component folder, I've created a file named `package.json` with the following configuration.

```
 {
   "main":"./comp1.component.tsx"
 }
```

And it works just fine, and in terms of `import` here is the result

```
components
|+comp1
|     - comp1.component.tsx
|     - comp1.styles.tsx
|     - package.json
|+comp2
|     - comp2.component.tsx
|     - comp2.styles.tsx

|...
|
```

```
import Comp1 from "../components/comp1/"
import Comp2 from "../components/comp2/"
import Comp3 from "../components/comp3/"
import Comp4 from "../components/comp4/"
```

All these approaches are working, but the main problem remains :

> having too many components import statements

**3rd Approach**
To try to solve this, I've created a file called `index.tsx` in the root of the `components folder` and for each of my components I've used a `named export` like :
`export const Comp1:React.FC<Comp1Pros>=(props)=>{...}`

And in my `index.tsx` file here is what I've done:

```
components
|+comp1
|     - comp1.component.tsx
|     - comp1.styles.tsx
|+comp2
|     - comp2.component.tsx
|     - comp2.styles.tsx
|...
|-index.tsx
|
```

```
export * from "./components/comp1/"
export * from "./components/comp2/"
export * from "./components/comp3/"
export * from "./components/comp4/"
```

When I import them it's more readable and with less code :

`import {Comp1,Comp2} from "../components"`

I really it, but what I fear is the above syntax is a `destructuring` syntax, so even if I'm only making use of `Comp1` and `Comp2` I'm importing all the component every time, and I think that this may be a performance issue especially for production build because any component is importing all the other `app` components.

So that what I've tried to, but the last one is the best for me and fits my needs, but has performance issues.

Do you have any idea about how I can achieve the same goal without creating a `performance issue`?

Note! I'm not a native English person, so please understand that my writing isn't perfect.

Comment: Why do you think that "having to much components import statements" is a problem? It isn't. The bundler (webpack or similar) will compile all that for you and just handle it.

Comment: Yeah, understand but the question is that with this syntax `import {Comp1,Comp2} from "../components"`, i'm only using to components `Comp1` and `Comp2` that i get through destructuring, btu all the other available component are also loaded right?